# How can i use specific string of label text data as a weblink

Tags: iphone, html

hi i  created customized cell table. in that, i printed data in label it has 60 lines, my query is i want to access specific string  from that label data as a web link. that means when i click on that string it should go to  the web page.

**EDIT :**  i have data with more strings in the data having one particular string for URL if click on that i want to hit webview with that url , if i click on other text don't do anything...

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add a single tap gesture recognizer to the UILabel and then open Safari in the selector that handles the gesture.

Something like:

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = @"Text here";
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(webLinkPressed:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[label addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer1];
[tapRecognizer1 release];
```

Then in your `webLinkPressed:` method, you can open the web browser.

Comment: i dont need total data. i have 50 lines of data in label in that i want to access only one string from that data as web link

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using UILabel u can use UITextView with Detection of links on. This will automatically handle the click on the link and open the URL in Safari.

Comment: i dont need total data. i have 50 lines of data in label in that i want to access only one string from that data as web link

Comment: @RajaReddyP just dont copy-paste your comment to all. Atulkumar is suggesting that if you could use a UITextView and set links detection, you can get event on weblinks from your 50 lines of code...

Comment: Thats the reason why I am suggesting u to use UITextView with links detection. This will identify the weblinks from the 50 line that u have and when u click on that link that will open safari.